# npm: how to find the latest compatible version of a dependency for a node module at a specific version?

Tags: node.js, npm, version, dependency-management

Is there a way to determine the latest version of a specific module which is compatible with another module at a specific version?

For example, running `npm install @angular/http` pulls `@angular/http@7.2.16` which dependes on `rxjs@^6.0.0`, but a lower version of `rxjs` is already present in the project — `rxjs@5.5.11`, and bumping this version will require updating a whole lot of other modules, which I want to avoid.

Is there a command that can show that the latest version of `@angular/http` which is compatible with `rxjs@5.5.11` is `x.y.z`?

There are tools like [`npmvet`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npmvet) which are good at displaying mismatched versions in the current project but can't find any tools which would show which versions can be used to resolve compatibility conflicts.

Answer (score 4):

it doesn't look like a tool exists, but using `npmvet` and `npm view` in this one line command was helpful in breaking this task down for me:

```
npmvet -r json | jq '.[] | .name + "@" + .packageVersion' | sed -e 's/"//g' | awk '{print "echo "$0"; npm view "$0" dependencies"}'|sh | tee ../deps.txt
```

this has output like so:

```
prismjs@1.23.0 !
prop-types@15.7.2
{
  'loose-envify': '^1.4.0',
  'object-assign': '^4.1.1',
  'react-is': '^16.8.1'
}
pug@3.0.1 !
pug-code-gen@2.0.3 !
raphael@2.2.8
{ 'eve-raphael': '0.5.0' }
rc-time-picker@3.4.0
{
  'babel-runtime': '6.x',
  classnames: '2.x',
  moment: '2.x',
  'prop-types': '^15.5.8',
  'rc-trigger': '^2.2.0'
}
react-collapsible@2.6.2
```

if you're like me and have got a pre-existing package.json with many dozens of packages/libs that have been allowed/required to diverge over time, you can use this output to help unpick the best matching versions until `npmvet` hopefully comes up green.

for example I started with this from npmvet:

[image]

searching through my deps.txt, I found:

```
prettier-eslint@11.0.0
{
  '@typescript-eslint/parser': '^3.0.0',
  'common-tags': '^1.4.0',
  dlv: '^1.1.0',
  eslint: '^6.8.0',
  'indent-string': '^4.0.0',
  'lodash.merge': '^4.6.0',
  'loglevel-colored-level-prefix': '^1.0.0',
  prettier: '^2.0.0',
  'pretty-format': '^23.0.1',
  'require-relative': '^0.8.7',
  typescript: '^3.9.3',
  'vue-eslint-parser': '~7.1.0'
}
```

I'm on `typescript@3.7.5`, but `prettier-eslint@11.0.0` wants `typescript@3.9.3`.

I then ran `npm i typescript@3.9.3` to satisfy the dependency, and `npmvet` is now matching for that package:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've never found a good way to do this but this tool makes it a little easier: [runpkg](https://www.runpkg.com/). It just allows you to browse different versions of a package from the npm registry. I like to just look at the `package.json` of different versions until I find one with compatible dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a hacky solution.

1. Create a dummy npm project with `npm init`
2. install all conflicting packages at once using single `npm install` command

   ```
   eg: `npm install package1 package2 package3`
   ```

most likely you'll find a non conflicting combination of packages.

But they might be conflicting with other existing packages